# Postgres :- update table row if id matches and datetime range is within 30 mins otherwise insert

Tags: database, postgresql

I have one table below with sample data.

Table_1:

```
| bid|first_nid|  first_datetime     |second_nid|  second_datetime    |third_nid|   third_datetime    |
|:--:|:-------:|:-------------------:|:--------:|:-------------------:|:-------:|:-------------------:|
| 06 |   6022  | 2023-04-10 14:51:53 |          |                     |         |                     |
| 20 |   6022  | 2023-04-10 14:13:18 |   6005   | 2023-04-10 14:14:24 |  6004   | 2023-04-10 14:14:59 |
| 27 |   6022  | 2023-04-15 09:29:00 |          |                     |         |                     |
| 17 |   6022  | 2023-04-15 08:29:00 |   6005   | 2023-04-15 08:31:00 |  6004   | 2023-04-15 08:32:00 |
```

I want to insert OR update below rows one by one in table-1 based on below conditions:-

- If bid & first_nid matches AND first_datetime is within 30 mins AND second_nid IS NULL in Table_1 then update second_nid, second_datetime, third_nid, third_datetime if Raw data having values, otherwise ignore.
- If bid & first_nid matches AND first_datetime is within 30 mins AND second_nid IS NOT NULL in Table_1 then ignore Raw data.
- If bid & first_nid matches AND is not within 30 mins then insert

Raw Data needs to be insert in Table_1-

```
| bid|first_nid|  first_datetime     |second_nid|  second_datetime    |third_nid|   third_datetime    |
|:--:|:-------:|:-------------------:|:--------:|:-------------------:|:-------:|:-------------------:|
| 06 |   6022  | 2023-04-10 15:55:53 |          |                     |         |                     |
| 27 |   6022  | 2023-04-15 09:35:00 |   6005   | 2023-04-15 09:36:28 |  6004   | 2023-04-15 09:37:28 |
| 17 |   6022  | 2023-04-15 08:28:00 |          |                     |         |                     |
```

Final Output -

```
| bid|first_nid|  first_datetime     |second_nid|  second_datetime    |third_nid|   third_datetime    |
|:--:|:-------:|:-------------------:|:--------:|:-------------------:|:-------:|:-------------------:|
| 06 |   6022  | 2023-04-10 14:51:53 |          |                     |         |                     |<- no changes
| 06 |   6022  | 2023-04-10 15:55:53 |          |                     |         |                     |<- insert    
| 20 |   6022  | 2023-04-10 14:13:18 |   6005   | 2023-04-10 14:14:24 |  6004   | 2023-04-10 14:14:59 |<- no changes
| 27 |   6022  | 2023-04-15 09:29:00 |   6005   | 2023-04-15 09:36:28 |  6004   | 2023-04-15 09:37:28 |<- update
| 17 |   6022  | 2023-04-15 08:29:00 |   6005   | 2023-04-15 08:31:00 |  6004   | 2023-04-15 08:32:00 |<- no changes(ignore raw data)
```

Setup table queries:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_1 (
bid character varying(2) NOT NULL,
first_nid character varying(5) NOT NULL,
first_datetime timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
second_nid character varying(5),
second_datetime timestamp without time zone,
third_nid character varying(5),
third_datetime timestamp without time zone, PRIMARY KEY(bid, first_nid, first_datetime));

INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES
      (06, '6022', '2023-04-10 14:51:53', '', NULL, '', NULL)
    , (20, '6022', '2023-04-10 14:13:18', '6005', '2023-04-10 14:14:24', '6004', '2023-04-10 14:14:59')
    , (27, '6022', '2023-04-15 09:29:00', '', NULL, '', NULL)
    , (17, '6022', '2023-04-15 08:29:00', '6005', '2023-04-15 08:31:00', '6004', '2023-04-15 08:32:00')
    ;
```

Comment: This would be relatively easy and straightforward with a PL/pgSQL block or function.

Comment: Hi @Stefanov.sm can you please provide the solution, I am not good in plsql. Thank you

Comment: I got the solution for this -

Comment: I was planning to write a few lines of pl/pgsql but you were faster :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this -

```
DO $$                  
    BEGIN 
        IF EXISTS
            ( SELECT 1 FROM table_1 WHERE bid = '27' AND first_nid='6022'
              AND (((first_datetime - '2023-04-15 09:35:00') >= '-00:30:00'::interval) AND ((first_datetime - '2023-04-15 09:35:00') <= '00:30:00'::interval))
            )
        THEN
            UPDATE table_1 SET second_nid = COALESCE(NULLIF(second_nid, ''), '6005'), 
            second_datetime = COALESCE(second_datetime, '2023-04-15 09:36:28'), 
            third_nid = COALESCE(NULLIF(third_nid, ''), '6004'), 
            third_datetime = COALESCE(third_datetime, '2023-04-15 09:37:28') WHERE bid = '27' AND first_nid='6022'
              AND (((first_datetime - '2023-04-15 09:35:00') >= '-00:30:00'::interval) AND ((first_datetime - '2023-04-15 09:35:00') <= '00:30:00'::interval));
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO table_1 values ('27','6022','2023-04-15 09:35:00','6005', '2023-04-15 09:36:28', '6004', '2023-04-15 09:37:28');
        END IF ;
    END
   $$ ;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).